# Unexpected behavior of javafx Text after Scale transform

Tags: javafx

I am developing javafx gui for a numerical model and it contains model visualization with text nodes. Whole model (composed from nodes and groups) is contained in Group and transformed by Scale and Translate transformations. All nodes (circles, lines and so on) behave as expected but Text nodes behave wrong. I made following simplest example showing the problem:

[running app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTNJb.png)

It should show two similar texts "Text bug", but only one is shown as expected. It seem that there is something wrong with scaling of the text attributes.
Thx for help.

```
import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextTransformBug extends Application
{


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    Pane root=new Pane();
    Scene scene=new Scene(root,300,250);
    //
    primaryStage.setTitle("Text bug");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    //
    //text nodes
    Text text1=new Text("Text bug1");
    text1.setFont(new Font("Verdana",0.1d));
    //
    Text text2=new Text("Text bug2");
    text2.setFont(new Font("Verdana",40d));
    //
    //group for text1
    Group group=new Group();
    group.getChildren().add(text1);
    //
    //transforms1
    Translate translate1=new Translate();
    translate1.setX(30d);
    translate1.setY(100d);
    //
    Scale scale=new Scale();
    scale.setPivotX(0d);
    scale.setPivotY(0d);
    scale.setX(400d);
    scale.setY(400d);
    group.getTransforms().addAll(translate1,scale);
    //
    //transforms2
    Translate translate2=new Translate();
    translate2.setX(30d);
    translate2.setY(200d);
    text2.getTransforms().addAll(translate2);
    //
    //final
    root.getChildren().addAll(group,text2);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the case, but maybe teh algorithm calculating the symbol positions of teh text rounds the positions to full pixels positioning the cars for a size significantly smaller than 1 on top of each other. (That's just a guess though).

Comment: Yes, but it does not make sense because double numbers everywhere. Additionally, as I understand, those characters are represented as curved paths and their render is not affected by the scale, only positions of characters are bugged.